# Android SDK w/Eclipse on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have downloaded and extracted the latest Android SDK. I used the AVD manager and installed ALL available packages (if if I won't need all of them).  I have eclipse installed, and set up with ADT.  I have the android SDK path set up correctly in eclipse. I have an AVD defined for the testing with the emulator.

Now, I can successfully create a new Android Project (hello world) which works just fine in the emulator.  I have fiddled with a few Hello World tutorials, all with success... Now for the problems...

1)  In the Eclipse console window, I always have these 2 errors: (again, everything appears to work fine!)

```
[2011-03-11 19:17:08 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Unable to read /AndroidManifest.xml: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory)
[2011-03-11 19:17:08 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Unable to read /AndroidManifest.xml: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory)
```

2)  I downloaded the MMS sources with git. I want to modify the stock MMS application.  I create a new Android project and chose to "Create project from existing source", where I point it to the MMS source directory.  When I try to run it, I get hundreds of errors (I'll paste a few here)

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
AcknowledgeInd cannot be resolved to a type RetrieveTransaction.java    /ConversationList/src/com/android/mms/transaction   line 222    Java Problem
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Addr cannot be resolved AddressUtils.java   /ConversationList/src/com/android/mms/util  line 47 Java Problem
```

How can I fix these errors?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try some / any of the following

- Close Eclipse and start it back up.
- Clean the relevant projects (Project -> Clean)
- Run Eclipse in Terminal as: Eclipse -clean
- Or perhaps this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404553/missing-androidmanifest-xml-when-importing-an-old-android-project-into-eclipse) would help (about how to import projects correctly)

Answer (score 0):

1st type of error sometimes happen if project is not built properly. You can just clean the project and ignore it as long as your code is running fine.

2nd type of error I guess has nothing to do with first type. I think some Java classes are missing or it is referencing to some library which is not available in your project.

Answer (score 0):

MMS can't be built as an SDK application, you should do it as part of a full Android build.

Comment: Are you sure of this,  I was pretty sure that MMS was just an app like any other 3rd party MMS app and wasn't actually an integral part of the OS, as it uses API calls to handle all the backend work