# No command output when running issue

Tags: android, r.java-file, failed-installation

Am having an error [Project has no default.properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649856/project-has-no-default-properties-file).

When I resolved that error am having an error with R.java. R.java is not generated while i clean the project. Also am getting 4 errors on error log. Am having the Error,

1. No command output when running: `m start -n com.helloandroid.canvastutorial/com.helloandroid.canvastutorial.Canvastutorial -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` on device emulator-5554
2. Failed to load properties file for project 'SplashScreen'
3. Unable to read E:\android-sdk\AndroidManifest.xml: java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\android-sdk\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
4. Failed to load properties file for project 'post-a-card_26_09_2012_SourceCode'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288058/failed-to-load-properties-file-for-android-project

Comment: still you are facing same problem ?

Answer (score 0):

R.java file won't get generated if there is some problem with your layouts or the setup of the project. So first try to resolve any errors in your project and then clean the project , R.java will be generated.

try this :
right-click project -> android tools -> fix project properties